# How to display a TV channel and computer monitor at the same time on LCD TV

Tags: display, tv

I need a way to diplay a TV channel (or DVD) and the PC monitor at the same time on a LCD TV. Can you suggest a way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Picture in Picture". Check your TV manual to see if your TV supports this.